# Try to understand more about Javascript -Node.js Async call stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callstack

If I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/:name', function(req, res, next) {

  let name = req.params.name;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    res.render('index', { title: name });
  },18000);

});

module.exports = router;
```

I open the browser and try to request this API many times with different values for name parameter in the sametime, for example: 
localhost:3000/param1 , localhost:3000/param2, localhost:3000/param3
Based on the concept of call stack with JavaScript, why name in setTimeOut callback gets the same value of `req.params.name` with every request.
Please check the screenshot.[image]

Comment: _gets the same value_ - what value?

Comment: "why name in setTimeOut callback gets the same value of req.params.name with every request" — What makes you think it is the same?

Comment: Sounds like in your actual code you might be missing a `let` or `var` to properly declare `name`.

Comment: …or your client code is not able to cope with concurrent requests.

Comment: @Quentin, if I send request: localhost:3000/param1, name = req.params.name, so the same value of name is the same value of name that inside setTimeout

Comment: @Elbassel — Well yes. That's standard variable scope in JS. Why wouldn't that happen?

Comment: @Elbassel are you _sure_ that you are declaring the `name` variable properly?

Comment: @Quentin, The problem is when req.get done in the call stack, it is removed from call stack, after that setTimeOut move from event queue to call stack to be executed.
So, if the req.get is removed from the call stack, why variable name still exist with a valua?

Comment: @Elbassel — Because variable scope has nothing to do with the call stack. They are independent of each other.